# Print multiple lines starting with "D" after multiple greps

Tags: command-line, bash, awk, text-processing

I have two text files. Text-file-1 contains strings (one string per line);

```
C 010
C 020
C 024
.
.
.
```

Text-file-2 contains data in following format;

```
C 005 Carbon
D Carbon 1
D Carbon 2
D Carbon 3
D Carbon 4
C 010 Hydrogen
D Hydrogen 1
D Hydrogen 2
C 017 Oxygen
D Oxygen 1
C 020 Nitrogen
D Nitrogen 1
D Nitrogen 2
D Nitrogen 3
C 024 Sulphur
D Sulphur 1
D Sulphur 2
.
.
.
```

Text-file-1 contains 30 lines but Text-file-2 contain huge data, and in the same format as I mentioned. I can grep the text in Text-file-2 found in Text-file-1 using following command;

```
awk 'NR==FNR { A[$2]=1; next }; A[$2]' Text-file-1 Text-file-2 > filename
```

Output for this script

```
C 010 Hydrogen
C 020 Nitrogen
C 024 Sulphur
.
.
.
```

My Desired output is;

```
C 010 Hydrogen
D Hydrogen 1
D Hydrogen 2
C 020 Nitrogen
D Nitrogen 1
D Nitrogen 2
D Nitrogen 3
C 024 Sulphur
D Sulphur 1
D Sulphur 2
.
.
.
```

Now, I need an extension of this command, which could print all lines (starting with "D"), including and after this line. All lines in Text-file-2 are starting with a letter (C or D). This letter is not useful for me, but I kept it. Kindly help.

Comment: Hi! This site is specific about Ubuntu, your question is not. You should ask on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini That doesn't make the question off-topic. As long as Muhammad wants answers that work on Ubuntu, and isn't interested in other Linux distributions, the question is perfectly on-topic here.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I agree with on this, this question *is* accepted here if all he wants is this to work on Ubuntu.  Having said this, this would also have worked on Stack Overflow because coding/programming.  However, in either case, the question *is* on topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another possible solution, using `sed`

```
while read str; do sed -n "/^$str/,/^C/ {/^$str/p;/^D/p}" Text-file-2; done < Text-file-1
```

Be aware that substituting shell variables into `sed` expressions should be used with care. It's OK in this case because `Text-file-1` contains simple alphanumeric strings, but it will fail if the shell variable contains any 'special' characters that need to be escaped within the sed expression.

Comment: Dear steeldriver, I think its working for me. I will try for my rest files. If got any trouble, I will contact you.

Comment: OK yes please let us know if you need further help - also I have edited my answer to add a warning about general usage

Answer (score 2):

Here's an `awk` script that does what you want:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR { C[$2]=1; next }
  $1 == "C" { if (C[$2] == 1) { print; D[$3]=1 } }
  $1 == "D" { if (D[$2] == 1) print }
' f1 f2
```

#### Example

Here's some sample data.

```
$ cat f1
C 010
C 020
C 024

$ cat f2
C 005 Carbon
D Carbon 1
D Carbon 2
D Carbon 3
D Carbon 4
C 010 Hydrogen
D Hydrogen 1
D Hydrogen 2
C 017 Oxygen
D Oxygen 1
C 020 Nitrogen
D Nitrogen 1
D Nitrogen 2
D Nitrogen 3
C 024 Sulphur
D Sulphur 1
D Sulphur 2
```

#### Results

```
$ awk '
>   NR==FNR { C[$2]=1; next }
>   $1 == "C" { if (C[$2] == 1) { print; D[$3]=1 } }
>   $1 == "D" { if (D[$2] == 1) print }
> ' f1 f2
C 010 Hydrogen
D Hydrogen 1
D Hydrogen 2
C 020 Nitrogen
D Nitrogen 1
D Nitrogen 2
D Nitrogen 3
C 024 Sulphur
D Sulphur 1
D Sulphur 2
```

You can put the `awk` script into it's own file like so, `cmd.awk`:

```
NR==FNR { C[$2]=1; next }
$1 == "C" { if (C[$2] == 1) { print; D[$3]=1 } }
$1 == "D" { if (D[$2] == 1) print }
```

Then run it like so:

```
$ awk -f cmd.awk f1 f2
C 010 Hydrogen
D Hydrogen 1
D Hydrogen 2
C 020 Nitrogen
D Nitrogen 1
D Nitrogen 2
D Nitrogen 3
C 024 Sulphur
D Sulphur 1
D Sulphur 2
```

Comment: Ohh, thats great. Thank you slm. I will ckeck this one tomorrow and will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Your wants seem to be conflicting with what is currently possible.

If you want to print D from both files use the following: `cat file1 file2 | grep -E '^D.+'`

The problem is that if you do a cat, you'll no longer know the file names once piping so you'll have to do something like: `grep -El '^D.+' *`

Comment: See the difference between Text-file-2 and my desired output. I do not want to print the data for "Carbon" and "Oxygen".

Comment: Dear josten, thank you for your kind efforts. But this is grepping approx all data from file2. Meanwhile script of @steeldriver worked for me.